# Differences between libertine and libertinus packages regarding pdfTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex, libertine

Until now I did not switch to LuaTeX and prefer pdfTeX, because it's faster. Since some years I've been using the old libertine-legacy package, e.g. because I need the command `\libertingeGlyph`and `\biolinumGlyph`, which print a certain glyph.

On the long run I'll have to dismiss libertine-legacy and replace it either with [libertine](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertine) or the fork [libertinus](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinus).

Can somebody point out differences between these two packages with regard to pdfTeX, which I'm using?

And how I can use e.g. roman numbering without the `\libertineGlyph`command, which used to provide the roman numbering glyphs from libertine in an example like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}

I'd like to use a Roman Number, but how to do without \libertineGlyph{Oneroman}

\end{document}
```

Or how can I define the two mentioned commands, either with libertine or libertinus-package?

Comment: I have no idea about fonts, but it seems to me that `libertine-legacy` defines many additional font families to get around the 256(?) character limit per family. So you can access these special characters by being internally re-routed to another font family. The new `libertine` package does not do these shenanigans and so you can only access the 256 characters per family.

Comment: Since last september there is also a [`libertinus-type1` package on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinus-type1). Herbert Voss has written [a wrapper package `libertinus`](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinus).

Answer (score 2):

> Can somebody point out differences between these two packages with regard to pdfTeX

libertinus (and libertinus-otf) will not work with pdf(la)tex. Use libertine (or libertine-legacy) or use xelatex (or lualatex) with libertinus and libertinus-otf.

Comment: Yes, I looked into the package libertinus and found only *.otf files. Whenever I find time I'll dive into the libertine.sty of the new libertine package and try to find out, if the `\libertineGlyph`command is included or how to define it.

Comment: As already mentioned, the \...Glyph commands are defined for use with the otf fonts.  See Section D.4  of the documentation for explanation of how the commands are defined.

Comment: At least nowadays, libertinus can also use libertinus-type1 which works on pdf(la)tex.

Answer (score 0):

You mention lua(la)tex but not xe(la)tex.  Using the libertine package with xelatex, the \libertineGlyph and \biolinumGlyph commands should be available.